# Fatal Error Premature end of file ERROR in React Native

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, android-studio, npm

[![Hi, I am trying to build the react native app.

> cd android/.gradlew clean

=> build success. But,

> npx react-native run-android

command gives this error. **[Fatal Error] :-1:-1: Premature end of file**.

I tried to build same app in android studio. Here also , getting same errors. It's been 3 or 4 days I am trying to resolve this. But, not getting how to fix this. Someoen please help me.][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vg3Lz.png)][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vg3Lz.png)  [image]

[image]